# Continuous Mapping of Three-dimensional surfaces

Tags: numerical-methods, homotopy-theory, computational-mathematics

If I have two sampled surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$  (discrete points) is there a nice way (or algorithm) to form a continuous map between the two, if the surfaces are of different sizes? That is, what is the best way to construct a continuous map between $\{ x_i^1, y_i^1, z_i^1 \}_{i=1}^n$  and $\{x_j^2, y_j^2, z_j^2\}_{j=1}^m$? Also, how about when I construct bivariate splines for both surfaces, is there a nice way to construct a map between the two as well?

Comment: Would a constant map work for you?

Comment: I presume this is for general data. The only think I can think about is bezier curves or bivariate spline.However, you would have to use some numerical root solvers in your mapping.